# Buttons Back, Leave and Cancel are inoperative in Hierarchical ALV

Tags: abap, alv

I display a hierarchical ALV. When I click the BACK or LEAVE or CANCEL buttons (in the toolbar), I'm supposed to go back or leave the program or cancel .

But when I click one of those buttons an additional row appends in the ALV hierarchy.

Any help ?

Comment: I could find a solution to a problem I had, close to yours: I had an erroneous line of code after I click the Back button in a column tree view inside a docking container. This line of code added a line to the tree view. By removing this line of code, I think this will correct your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check yor PBO/PAI moduls.

EXAMPLE:

IN PBO i said

```
module status_0100 output.
  set pf-status 'GUI_STATUS_0100'.
  " and some other code
  " and some other code
 endmodule.
```

IN PAI i said

```
 module user_command_0100 input.   

        case sy-ucomm.
          when 'CANCEL' or 'BACK'.
            set screen 0.
          when 'EXIT'.
            leave program.
        endcase.

     endmodule.
```

In GUI_STATUS_0100 i told about buttons that i used[image]

It might help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There must be event(s) trigger along side with BACK, LEAVE and CANCEL.

Double check the function code of 3 buttons, ensure they only appears in Exit-command and when triggered, ensure there is no other subroutines inside/next to the LEAVE, RETURN... statement

If possible, please post some code.